# Wrap child when using 3th party plugin

Tags: javascript, html, css, highcharts

I am using highcharts plugin to create a chart.

My problem is that i want to set the height and width in a relative way.

I tried wrapping it and setting the width as relative but the height still uses the child's height and not the parent(wrapper).

```
<div style="width:60vw; height:40vh">
     <div id="overallAlerts"></div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
window.chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'overallAlerts'
        },
.....
```

ScreenShot:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is likely that you're not defining any height on your child element, forcing the chart to revert to its default values.

The [Highstock documentation](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#chart.height) states:

> **height : Number**
>
> An explicit height for the chart. By default the height is calculated from the offset height of the containing element, **or 400 pixels if the containing element's height is 0**.

Simply add in a `height` and `width` of `100%`:

```css
#overallAlerts {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Or, if you really insist on using inline-styling:

```
<div id="overallAlerts" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;"></div>
```

Comment: problem is that if you see the documentation, you cannot use '%' when setting height and width, thats the big problem,

Comment: "The height is calculated from the offset height". The offset height will be a value in pixels, not %.

Comment: I tried not setting anything, but it overleys the parrent, see my edit

Comment: @user3770158 not setting anything will make it default to 400px. Set the `height` and `width` on your `overallAlerts` element to `100%`, as my answer says.

Comment: @user3770158 set `height` to `100%` on your `overallAlerts` element's CSS.